# How can I create an iterable generic class that runs on two generic types?

Tags: java, data-structures, iterator

How can I create an iterable generic class that runs on two generic types?

That is, if I have a class called:

```
public class PriorityQueue<K,V> {}
```

how can I implement `Iterable` if I am unable to use `implements Iterable<K,V>`? Eclipse is giving an error saying:

> Incorrect number of arguments for type Iterable; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

I must be misunderstanding how to implement my own iterable collection.

And on this subject: Do I want to make my priorityqueue iterable, or do I make my entries that the queue stores iterable?

---

Edit:

For my homework assignment, I have to implement the PriorityQueue ADT in a linked list fashion. I've implemented all the methods save for one -- `min()`. The way I'm thinking of doing it is iterating over all the `Entry` objects stored in my list by making a private `entries()` method. But I have no idea how to approach this.

I have right now a link to the head of the linked list and a link to the tail. How can I make said `entries()` method so that I can return an `Iterable` object of the entries?

Here's my `Entry<K,V>` object:

```
public class Entry<K,V> implements Comparable {

  private V _value;
  private K _key;
  private Entry<K,V> _prev;
  private Entry<K,V> _next;

  public Entry(K key, V value) {
    this._value = value;
    this._key = key;
    this._prev = null;
    this._next = null;
  }

  public V getValue() {
    return this._value;
  }

  public K getKey() {
    return this._key;
  }

  public Entry<K,V> getNext() {
    return _next;
  }

  public void setNext(Entry<K,V> link) {
    this._next = link;
  }

  public Entry<K,V> getPrev() {
    return _prev;
  }

  public void setPrev(Entry<K,V> link) {
    this._prev = link;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    if (arg0 instanceof Entry<?,?>) {

    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

And here's my `PriorityQueue<K,V>` so far:

```
public class PriorityQueue<K,V> implements Iterable<K>{

  private Entry<K,V> _head;
  private Entry<K,V> _tail;
  private int _size;

  public PriorityQueue() {
    this._head = null;
    this._tail = null;
    this._size = 0;
  }

  public int size() {
    return _size;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (size() == 0);
  }

  public Entry<K,V> min() {

  }

  public Entry<K,V> insert(K k, V x) {
    Entry<K,V> temp = new Entry<K,V>(k,x);
    if (_tail == null) {
      _tail = temp;
      _head = temp;
    }
    else {
      _tail.setNext(temp);
      temp.setPrev(_tail);
      _tail = temp;
    }
    return temp;
  }

  public Entry<K,V> removeMin() {
    Entry<K,V> smallest = min();
    smallest.getPrev().setNext(smallest.getNext());
    smallest.getNext().setPrev(smallest.getPrev());

    return smallest;
  }

  @Override
  public Iterator<K> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use java's PriorityQueue?

Comment: I have to make my own for a homework assignment.

Comment: @BheshGurung I did that, actually. I'll include the code for it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a wrapper class for the returned Iterable object.  In your case I assume it to be type Entry.  So as an example, your code should look like:

```
public class PriorityQueue<K, V> implements Iterable<Entry<K, V>> {
}
```

Of course, you can always create a custom wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Iterable means you can iterate over objects of its type. It accepts one type parameter.
From the documentation:

> public interface Iterable
>
> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the "foreach" statement.

If you want it to be Iterable over your keys your class should implement `Iterable<K>`.
If you want it to be Iterable over your values your class should implement  `Iterable<V>`.

Here is a [blog post](http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/03/javas-iterators-and-iterables.html) about implementing Iterable.

Normally, you want to make the entries that the queue stores iterable, you also might want to figure out in what order.

If you're wandering about implement a Priority Queue you might also want to take a look at Java's own [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) implementation and follow that.

Comment: Rather than just implementing `Iterable<K>` you could also implement `Iterable<Pair<K,V>>` or something following that vein.

Comment: @Servy That's an intersting point, the OP did not make it clear what he wants to iterate over. Java's own PriorityQueue does not have a Key type parameter but only a value type parameter, it implements iterable in a way that iterates through its values.

Comment: Well, a priority queue generally doesn't have keys and values, but it's possible to provide a key and a value separately, rather than just values and a way of comparing two values to determine which has a higher priority.  While it's not the standard implementation, it is a sensible one in certain contexts.

Comment: That's interesting, I did not know that. Do you have any reading material on the matter? I only remember PriorityQueues in the context of heaps :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've updated my question... Maybe you can give a bit more details on how I can approach this?

Comment: @agent154 It appears to me you need more theoretical guidance and less of a practical answer to a specific problem, if you'd like more help we can continue this discussion in chat.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's the same idea.  In the library PQ it only holds objects, but has some means of comparing them based on a priority.  The PQ never knows what the underlying priority is, it just has a comparer method and lets the class itself sort it out.  An alternative is for the `Add` method to accept both a priority to compare on, and then an actual value that the priority maps to, which is only really used as something to look at when you pull the values out.  A heap is simply how you structure the pairs of object and determine which pair to spit out.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm in the Java room - first time I've ever used chat.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Actually, I have to leave for the moment to get a bus home. I'll have to check for you later. Thanks for the offer to help though.